# Why after pressing $ in normal mode Vim goes to the last symbol in line, but in visual mode it goes on the /n newline symbol?

Tags: cursor-movement

Is it possible to change that somehow? Either to make Vim go one symbol further in normal mode, or one symbol less in visual mode?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make `$` go one symbol further in normal mode by enabling setting `virtualedit=onemore` and remapping `$` to `g$`.

```
:set virtualedit=onemore
:nnoremap $ g$
```

---

As @statox mentions in the comments

You can also make $ go one symbol less in visual mode with the following mapping:

```
:vnoremap $ $h
```

Comment: Just a note to complete the answer: OP also mentioned the possibility to go one symbol less in visual mode which can be done with `:vnoremap $ $h`

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there's no built-in way to stop visual mode from being *inclusive* and normal mode from being *exclusive*.

One could probably remap everything to work like that but that sounds like a bad idea to me.